# how to create smooth favicon transparency for internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, transparency, favicon

for firefox and chrome i use a png as my favicon which allows me to use nice smooth alpha transparency. However, internet explorer doesn't display my png favicon, so i have to use ico which only supports 1bit transparency (as far as i know?).

however - If I look at the favicon of stackoverflow in internet explorer, then it also shows smooth transparency.

How's that done?

Comment: [Doesn't look smoothly transparent to me.](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico)

Comment: andreas: why not? it seems to have 8bit transparency

Answer (score 2):

IE supports `ico` as favicon so all you need to do is use any imaging software to generate an `ico` from your `png` image

I use [@Icon Sushi](http://www.towofu.net/soft/e-aicon.php) (you can use Photoshop, Fireworks, Paint.NET, etc)

just drag your image into there, selected it and **Save as ico** and it will maintain all transparencies.

http://www.adwiza.com/t/2011-08-12_0955.png

Answer (score 0):

*Update* - IE 11 supports PNG for Favicons.

I believe the best method would be balexandre's method. But another option would be to create the background color of your favicon to be what most people have as the standard color in the bar.

The background color is `#C0C0C0 or 192,192,192` but you would be required to save it as a ICO format as that is the only format IE supports. [See Here for favicon format support.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support)